# I got a pointer null exception on a linkedhashset

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
public class Tirage {
    private LinkedHashSet<Integer> grille;

    public Tirage(){
        Set<Integer> grille = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
    }

    public void ajouterNombre(Integer i) throws TirageException{
        if (i>= 1 && i<=90) {
            this.grille.add(i); //this is where i got the pointer null exception
        }
        else{
            throw new TirageException("Veuillez entrer un nombre conforme");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simple,

```
private LinkedHashSet<Integer> grille;
```

here you are not initializing the `grille` field,

and not even here,

```
public Tirage(){
        Set<Integer> grille = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
    }
```

So, just do this,

```
public Tirage(){
       this.grille = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
    }
```

this will initialize your `grille` field with a new object instance.

Comment: I'd suggest using `this.grille = new ...` to be most explicit that you want to initialize the instance property of `this` class

Answer (score 0):

`this.grille` has not been instantiated in that context. In your constructor you are creating a different instance of a different type even.

Remove the type of the private variable in your constructor:

```
public Tirage(){
    grille = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
}
```